# WooCommerce Hook for Javascript Event

Tags: javascript, woocommerce, event-handling

My goal here is to trigger:

```
('button.save-action').trigger('click');
```

After adding a product in the admin order creator because I am adding meta via the woocommerce_ajax_add_order_item_meta event but it will not show to the admin until either recalculate or save button is clicked.

here: plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/admin/meta-boxes-order.min.js:333 (need to reformat / unminify to see line number) I found this code:

```
    success: function( response ) {
                    if ( response.success ) {
                        $( '#woocommerce-order-items' ).find( '.inside' ).empty();
                        $( '#woocommerce-order-items' ).find( '.inside' ).append( response.data.html );

                        // Update notes.
                        if ( response.data.notes_html ) {
                            $( 'ul.order_notes' ).empty();
                            $( 'ul.order_notes' ).append( $( response.data.notes_html ).find( 'li' ) );
                        }

                        wc_meta_boxes_order_items.reloaded_items();
                        wc_meta_boxes_order_items.unblock();
                    } else {
                        wc_meta_boxes_order_items.unblock();
                        window.alert( response.data.error );
                    }
                },
                complete: function() {
                    window.wcTracks.recordEvent( 'order_edit_add_products', {
                        order_id: woocommerce_admin_meta_boxes.post_id,
                        status: $( '#order_status' ).val()
                    } );
                },
                dataType: 'json'
            });
```

Is there a way to listen to either this event:

```
window.wcTracks.recordEvent( 'order_edit_add_products', {
```

I have tried code like this but it doesn't work:

```
jQuery().on('order_edit_add_products',function(){console.log('event triggered')})
```

I also saw this reference but I don't think this way works either: https://nebula.gearside.com/how-to-use-the-javascript-wordpress-hooks-api-without-any-extra-libraries/